# Getting certain parts of a string out of a select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, replace

I have a database (mydb) with following data in one column:

**PK:**

- 8/10/6101+6102 (2971386)
- 6110/2411 (3037457)
- 8/10/6504 (2276770)
- 8/10/6403 (2724296)
- -2669938
- 8/1/1001-1031 (2857109)
- -2547251
- 8/9/5003-5006 (2770096)

I have to compare these data with a variable `$id` for example: 2724296

```sql
SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE PK = '$id';
```

Of course, this query won't deliver a result. Is there a easy way to compare my $id with the values in the brace and the values with no brace? A replace in the select replaces e.g. only the brace, but not the value left to the brace.

Greets, Yab86

Comment: why are you using such a format in the db

Comment: A regex would probably do it, but if you want to compare you may also use PHP `explode` to accomplish it. Also, what's up with this kind of format..?

Comment: Aside from the bad database structure, why not use LIKE?

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column LIKE '%$id%'

Comment: you can use LIKE: as SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE PK LIKE '%$id%';

Comment: The format in the db is from a external import. I can not change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) for this. Try this query,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE PK REGEXP '({$id})' OR PK REGEXP '-{$id}'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below:

> SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE PK LIKE '%(2724296)';

Below is little complex: using regular expression

> SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE PK REGEXP '[(]2724296[)]';

See this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html for writing customizable regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a regular expression (assuming you only want to check the number inside the brackets). Something like this should work:

```
\([0-9]*\)$
```

This will return a string that begins with ( followed by 1 or more numbers and ends with ). You should then be able to remove the brackets from the string and compare it with your variable